# Is the a way to configure Notepad++ to use the Intellij keymap?

Tags: keyboard, ide, notepad++, editor

I'm coming from the PyCharm IDE (which uses the Intellij keyboard shortcuts) and moving to Notepad++ in order to learn C.

I would like Notepad++ to feature generally the same shortcuts I'm familiar with from PyCharm. Is there an easy way to do this? Some import-keymap feature? Or must I configure all shortcuts by hand?

Comment: Is anyone gonna answer this question?!?!

Comment: @Rules I ended up using Eclipse IDE with a highly-customized keymap to achieve this. It works fine :)

Comment: Eclipse IDE  Why not IDEA itself then?

Comment: IDEA doesn't do C unfortunately :) CLion does but it's paid.

Comment: Update if anyone's interested: I ended up using VS Code with the C/C++ extension and the IDEA keymap extension. Works generally great.